# Проиграть анимацию при попадании объекта на экран

Tags: javascript, html, css

Новичок. Делаю анимацию к объекту. Столкнулся с одной проблемой: все анимации проигрываются при загрузке страницы одновременно, но мне нужно, чтобы они проигрывались только при попадании объекта на экран. Как я могу это сделать?
Немного кода:

```css
@keyframes to-right {
    0% {transform: translate(-500px);}
    100% {transform: translate(0px);}
}

@keyframes to-left {
    0% {transform: translate(500px);}
    100% {transform: translate(0px);}
}

.animated-block1 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    animation: to-right 2.5s;
}

.animated-block2 {
    width: 250px;
    height: 250px;
    animation: to-left 2.5s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <div class="animated-block1" style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
  </div>
  <div class="animated-block2" style="background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API

Comment: Какой объект должен попасть на экран? Я не понял суть вопроса =)

Comment: @Хмельни́цький, у каждого объекта при попадании на экран должна проигрываться анимация, но если объект ещё не попал на экран, то анимацию проигрывать не нужно

Comment: Так ваш код двигает объект по экрану, значит нужно убрать эту анимацию? Вы непонятно излагаете свои мысли.